# Bulid Ajax in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I need to understand how to build Ajax request in Yii. I searched on the Yii website and found the following article :

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/

I wrote the code and I tested it on my localhost ? but for some reason it did not work.

For a first attempt I only wanted to do something simple. I wanted to print the result of another action on my page by using Ajax. The text that I want to be displayed is 'Hi'.

This is how mu code looks like for that action:

view/index

```
<?php
/* @var $this CurrentController */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
        'Current'=>array('/current'),
        'index',
);
?>
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'users-index-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList('country_id','', array(1=>'USA',2=>'France',3=>'Japan'),
array(
'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('currentController/dynamiccities'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
'update'=>'#city_id', //selector to update
//'data'=>'js:javascript statement' 
//leave out the data key to pass all form values through
))); 

//empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id','', array());


?>


<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Controller

```
<?php



class CurrentController extends Controller
{



public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','dynamiccities'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
        );
    }
public $country_id;
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }




public function actionDynamiccities() /// Called Ajax
{


        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>'2'),CHtml::encode('Text'),true);

}  



}
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting the desired result. What I get is:

1. drowpdown list contains country array.
2. another drowpdown list  but empty ?!

How should I fix my example code so it would work? Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: code seems good. can you please check this in Firebug ? and see really ajax request triggers.

Comment: GBD it's work : see my result on :
http://up.arabseyes.com/uploads/29_11_1213541819231.jpg

Comment: did you see `response header` in your snapshot ? it's 404

Comment: GBD , Why look like that ? have any idea !

Comment: Try to run URL you got from `CController::createUrl('currentController/dynamiccities')` directly into browser. Also paste your url manager code from `config/main.php`

Comment: GBD Problem was fixed
CController::createUrl('currentController/dynamiccities') 
To 
CController::createUrl('current/dynamiccities') 
:)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id','', array());
```

use id as

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id','', array('id'=>'city_id'));
```